# Can I use a paint pad to apply floor varnish?

Tags: flooring, varnishing

I went looking in the shop for a lambswool pad to apply floor lacquer, but they didn't have one, so I bought an Anza paint pad. Can I use this to coat a floor? Should I try to find a proper lambswool applicatyor, or just stick to brushes? I'm using Junkers 625 lacquer.

[image]

Comment: I don't know, however, test it on a piece of scrap wood (or in an unobtrusive corner of the room) to see if it works OK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend a "mohair" roller. This is a very short nap, lintless roller cover that applies varnish and urethanes fast and extremely smoothly.  I don't like pads at all, as they always seem to streak.

Comment: I went looking, but couldn't find a mohair roller, ended up using a paintbrush.

Answer (score 1):

I put a couple of coats on with the pad and it left bubbles on the surface. I ended up using a brush the same width as the floorboards I'd sanded (about 6 inches) and it made a much nicer finish.

Some tips:

- Apply the varnish along the grain
- Try to paint a whole board in one go, as the varnish dries and leaves marks at the area where you apply it next
- Store the brush in a plastic bag (in a fridge if you want) between coats to prevent it from drying out.
- Don't wear socks, you'll end up stepping in some varnish and leaving a sticky patch of fabric.